# Compass exported a document and trying to import a single document

Tags: mongodb

I exported a single document from Compass and now I'm trying to import it, but I'm getting `Unexpected end of JSON input`

Note: the JSON below shows a simplified version for the document, however the one below doesn't import either.

```
{
    "firstName": "Rod"
}
```

Comment: how do you import?

Comment: I go up to Collection on the File Menu and select Import Data then select the JSON option and file path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file should be in format 1 document per line:

```
{"firstName": "Rod"}
```

Comment: ok so i don't get the error anymore and it looks like it completed, but no documents appear in the collection

Comment: well, i exported the JSON and then that apparently put it in an importable form. I noticed oid property in a lot of the object ids

Comment: In your favorite editor, use regex to replace newline with space

Comment: Now you have two problems =)

Comment: This still doesnt work for me. I have multiple objects on each line, with no commas - like the docs say.  I still get `Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: @conor909 It should be 1 document per line. I can't stress it enough nor put it simpler.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, I have that.  I've followed the docs example.  It still doesn't work.  I have multiple objects in the file, each one on its own line.

Comment: @conor909 lol it was "multiple objects on each line" in your previous comment. Anyway the snippet from the answer does work. I am sure it will work even for you. If you are facing problems importing **your** data you'd better ask new question with examples of data you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

In Compass, I managed to get it to work with importing about 20 rows at a time, but it will always fail with my 10,000 rows, so it's not a good workaround for larger data files.

There is a known bug with MongoDB, and there is an ongoing Jira ticket open you can follow the progress of here:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3643

MongoDB recommends that you login and comment on this ticket.  Describing your use case and how this issue is critical to your usage of Compass.

"The best way to advocate for this feature request is to open a commercial support request and let us know how this is impacting your use of MongoDB." - MongoDB support